# ABAP DDD how to correctly implement add/update/remove child from aggregate via RFC?

Tags: domain-driven-design, abap

I'm trying to follow DDD principles for my current project. Unfortunately I have to use RFCs due to technical constraints, so no OData and no REST. It's quite a long question I hope it's OK to ask this in Stackoverflow.

In any case, I have an entity class WorkOrder with a list of Operation objects.

I have a WorkOrderRepository class with a SAVE method that only receives a WorkOrder object and is able to save everything (header data, address, etc) in one go. No matter if it's creation, update or deleted. The repository hides the BAPI calls from the rest.

Now I want to implement the logic to add/update/remove Operations to the work order object and I'm not sure even if the names I give to the methods are correct. Maybe they should be insert/edit/delete... I'm quite confused with this since in every place I look they use different names.

But the most important are my 2 specific doubts:

1. Should I have only 1 RFC that receives all the updates to a WorkOrder entity including header, operations? Or should I create 1 RFC per operation that only handles one operation at a time? Bear in mind that the UI mockup expects that the user can add/delete multiple operations before clicking a SAVE button and RFC has implicit commit, and that to my knowledge a DDD entity should be updated always in one call.

Option 1:

```
FUNCTION ZWORKORDER_HDR_UPD
  IMPORTING
    VALUE(I_WORKORDER_ID) TYPE AUFNR
    VALUE(I_WORKORDER_HDR_CHG) TYPE ZWORKORDER_HDR_CHG
    VALUE(I_WORKORDER_HDR_UPD) TYPE ZWORKORDER_HDR_UPD "X structure for the BAPI
    VALUE(I_OPERATIONS_CHG) TYPE ZOPERATIONS_CHG
    VALUE(I_OPERATIONS_UPD) TYPE ZOPERATIONS_UPD
    VALUE(I_OPERATIONS_DEL) TYPE ZOPERATIONS_DEL
  EXPORTING
    VALUE(E_ERRORS) TYPE BAPIRET2_T.
```

Option 2

```
FUNCTION ZWORKORDER_OPERATION_CRT
  IMPORTING
    VALUE(I_WORKORDER_ID) TYPE AUFNR
    VALUE(I_OPERATION) TYPE ZOPERATION_CHG
  EXPORTING
    VALUE(E_ERRORS) TYPE BAPIRET2_T.

FUNCTION ZWORKORDER_OPERATION_UPD
  IMPORTING
    VALUE(I_WORKORDER_ID) TYPE AUFNR
    VALUE(I_OPERATION_CHG) TYPE ZOPERATION_CHG
    VALUE(I_OPERATION_UPD) TYPE ZOPERATION_UPD
  EXPORTING
    VALUE(E_ERRORS) TYPE BAPIRET2_T.

  FUNCTION ZWORKORDER_OPERATION_DEL
      IMPORTING
        VALUE(I_WORKORDER_ID) TYPE AUFNR
        VALUE(I_OPERATION_ID) TYPE ZOPERATION_ID
      EXPORTING
        VALUE(E_ERRORS) TYPE BAPIRET2_T.
```

2. How should my Workorder methods look to handle this? I'm specially confused with the update method, since I'm not sure if I should first get the existing operation and then update it or let the parent class do it. But maybe my approaches are completely wrong from the root.

Option 1:

```
workorder->add_operation( i_operation ). "Pass flat structure from RFC? Or first create object?
workorder->update_operation( i_operation_chg
                             i_operation_upd ).
workorder->delete_operation( i_operation_id ).
```

Option 2:

```
workorder->add_operation( ).
operation = workorder->get_operation(i_operation_chg->get_id())
operation->update( i_operation_chg
                   i_operation_upd ).
operation->delete_operation( i_operation_id ).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is always the best ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles). It doesn't really matter if you create 1 or 3 RFC-enabled function module, so if you can achieve your goal with one function module, then do it with one.

1. I think you need to have two RFC-enabled function modules. One to validate the maintained operations (do the validations as far as possible), but that should not save anything to the database, and another one called after the user clicks the SAVE button, to save the whole "WorkOrder", including the maintained operations (at this time, there will be the complete validation also).
2. If you don't need to define an "operation" class for something else, **right now**, then keep it simple, no need to instantiate an object. Note that you may create an "operation" class with private static methods, and being a friend of the "workorder" class (only this class can use the operation class), just to organize better your code.

PS: although I don't know what is "Domain-Driven Design", I don't see how your question is related to it, because it just looks like simple program design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I deleted part of my question where I was explaining the DDD part because I realised it was not relevant at the end. But by DDD I just mean that my WO represents my specific business and hides all the BAPIs/ECC tables details (i.e. some partners are just single work order header fields in my WO).  Anyway, I want to create an operation object to handle more complexity like change of status based on business rules, I don't like too much the static methods approach, so I think I'll go for UPDATE option 2, getting the reference first. What do you think?

Comment: Adding some complex object-oriented code between two non-object-oriented concepts (UI and BAPI) may be counter-productive. It's just my opinion based on the information you gave. If you have other arguments, I could change my mind. For instance, if you want to automate the unit tests, then it's required to use instance members. Anyway, you can still take an intermediate approach, like having a "operation manager" singleton, that you instantiate once to manage all operations. Note that my answer was more about coding using KISS and YAGNI principles, I can't tell what the best solution is.

Answer (score 0):

We also work with DDD, although luckily not with RFCs but instead Gateway/OData. Since REST by defintion is stateless we always commit in our application service layer.

What we do is have three "DDD" entities
app_Service, domain_service, repository (and also some data containers like aggregates), where the app_service in your case would expose the methods create, update and delete, and possibly also validate.

Then I would write four thin RFCs (crud + validate) that basically passes the data to the app service.

As for being able to handle multiple updates in each save, we always model our OData (your RFC) after the UI requirements, then it's the app_service task to make sense of the data from a system point of view.

We make heavy use of Abap Clean Code (it's even part of our ATC check), and they clearly state that you should have seperate methods, which is also OO best practices.

https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#split-methods-instead-of-adding-optional-parameters