# Use structures to group individual attributes or not?

Tags: oop, attributes, abap

I'm in doubt of how to get the best of ABAP structures and class attributes.

Let's say that I have the object Operation with 4 fields: operation id, type, description and date.

Now I can create a class with this 4 attributes, but then if I want to have a constructor, I need either 4 individual parameters or a structure than needs to be mapped to each attribute. The same happens if I want to get all this object data in one structure, for instance to return via RFC. Then a method `get_operation_details( )` will need to map all of them one by one.

If I use a structure type `ty_operation_details` as a single class attribute, then when I add a field to the structure would also keep the constructor valid and the `get_operation_details( )` method would also be always OK. However it seems wrong to have something like `Operation->get_details( )-operationID`, instead of `operation->operation_ID` if I had the attribute directly in the public section with `READ-ONLY`. I guess the first approach is more correct in the OO world, but we lose some of the ABAP benefits.

What do you recommend to use? Maybe one thing it could allow the first option and use structures at the same time would be a `CORRESPONDING` statement able to map class attributes to a flat structure, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I opt for the first one (4 attributes, no structure), from far, but it's just my opinion. The only "benefit" you have with a structure is to avoid the "triple" redundancy of the 4 attributes (constructor parameters, attributes and initialization in the constructor). But the advantage becomes quickly horrible when you add code in the class itself and in "using" code.

Comment: Thanks. And then, would you use a structure as input parameter for the constructor or individual parameters? I know I stated only 4 in the question, but I have a few more.

Comment: The parameters of the constructor are usually those which identifies uniquely the object, or are obligatory to define the object when it's instantiated. If you have many parameters, it's probably a good idea to have structured parameters to group semantically-related fields. But if the context is like in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086406/abap-ddd-how-to-correctly-implement-add-update-remove-child-from-aggregate-via-r), maybe there's no added value to do it "right", and maybe I wouldn't do it the way I advise.

Comment: Excessive structuring in classes can make code unreadable and cumbersome and brings no benefits. If you want to semantically differentiate your attributes try to use prefixes, e.g. `fin_price`, `fin_vat` for financial attributes, `dim_length`, `dim_width` for dimensions, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most things, your design should follow your usage. If you primarily use a set of attributes together, consider grouping them in a structure. If you primarily use them individually, or in varying recombinations, keep them separate.

Some considerations:

- Grouping makes calls shorter if you always create/update/delete a set of attributes together. You already identified this advantage.
- Grouping reveals logical relations between fields, that are not clear when keeping the fields separate. For example, this could reveal that one part of your parameters is mandatory, while the rest forms several optional sets.
- Grouping simplifies features that operate on state, such as the Memento or the Flyweight pattern, in that it allows to extract, store, and restore the object's state as a single structure.

Also, like many other things, there may be benefit in turning this *either-or* question into a *I'll simply use both*. For example, if your class has four individual properties, why not still offer a method that sets or gets them as a structure; of course, this will add some mapping, but the mapping would remain encapsulated within your own class, while consumer get an easy-to-consume interface.

Comment: This is also what is suggested by Abap Clean Code, https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/master/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#aim-for-few-importing-parameters-at-best-less-than-three

"You can reduce the number of parameters by combining them into meaningful sets with structures and objects."

It's always a good idea to lean on the shoulders of giants